Shopify- Getting CORS error While calling GraphQl from store frontend
I am trying to implement something. In which I am using GraphQl to read the Product data front store frontend. But while API call I am getting a CORS error.
Error message:-

from origin 'store URL' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.'

I tried to check but I found nothing that helps.
Code:
  const response = await fetch(`https://test-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-04/graphql.json`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/graphql',
      'X-Shopify-Access-Token': "admin_token",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: `
        {
          product(id: "${productId}") {
            variants(first: 10) {
              edges {
                node {
                  id
                  inventoryItem {
                    id
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `,
    }),
  });

